# How to get he first lines of every file/s with a specific file extension

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So for example in a directory there are files with the .test file extension

And in a batch script I would want to extract the first lines of the files to variables ***no matter how many files*** (this is where it's hard for me)

And as a test I would display (echo) the lines extracted

How would I do that?

Here's what I could make:

```
dir /b *.test>testfileslist.temp
find /v /c "" <testfileslist.temp>filesnumber.temp
set /p filesnum=<filesnumber.temp
del filesnumber.temp
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear, so we can't give answers, but for `no matter how many files (this is where it's hard for me)`, try `for %%a in (*.test) do echo %%a` (batch file syntax. If you try it directly on command line, write `%a` instead of each `%%a`)

Comment: I forgot to mention that i would need the filenames for each file (that is why i created a temporary list of the files)

Comment: And I would name the variables for the first line of the files to be "_%file#:(file extension)=%-(whatever line1 should be, like a password or something)"

Comment: And i created a variable that tells how many files are there

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
rem The following settings for the source directory, destination directory, target directory,
rem batch directory, filenames, output filename and temporary filename [if shown] are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately include names which include spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.
SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"

:: remove variables starting ":"
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set : 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.txt" '
 ) DO (
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%t IN ("%sourcedir%\%%a") DO IF NOT DEFINED :%%a SET ":%%a=%%t"

)
SET :

GOTO :EOF
```

for each filename found matching the filemask (I used `*.txt`), establish a variable with name starting `:` (since `:` cannot be in a filename) and ignore the remainder of the file.

Note that I've assumed filenames do not contain spaces, commas or any of the batch-sensitive characters.